# Problem importing whatsapp-web.js nodejs module in electron react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, electron, sharp

I am trying to build an electron react app. I need to integrate this node modules https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatsapp-web.js in my electron react app. My main.js of electron looks like this:

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL("your ip address:3000");

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

And the React code where i want to import whatsapp-web.js module looks like

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const Client = require('whatsapp-web.js');
function Error() {
  var client = new Client();
  client.initialize();
  console.log(client);
  console.log(qrcode);
  return (
    <Container>
      <ErrorImage src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/smiley-vol-3-2/48/134-512.png"></ErrorImage>
      <ErrorMessage>Oops, you are not connected to any number.</ErrorMessage>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Error;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20vh;
  position: center;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: center;
`;

const ErrorImage = styled.img`
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: contain;

  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;

  /* border: 2px solid black; */
`;

const ErrorMessage = styled.div`
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  /* top: 20px; */
  font-size: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
`;
```

Now everytime I try to import const {Client} = require('whatsapp-web.js') It throws error like this:
**
**[0] ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
[0] Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg' in 'D:\Sunil\Zarir_app-main\Zarir_app-main\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg'
[0] Compiling...
[0] Failed to compile.**

and I tried the solution
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573#issuecomment-305408048
and other resources but still nothing works and just loops in errors and errors.
Please help if you have any information related to it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the webpack plugin are not in effect

try:

```sh
# mac or linux
export FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=

# win
set FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=

yarn run build
```

because:

[image]

fluent-ffmpeg relevant source code: [fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/index.js](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/master/index.js#L1)

If that doesn't work, I suggest you modify the node_modules source code and print above it: `process.env`, verify that the variable is valid.

final solution: use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)